# Can I create two (or more) forumus with myBB?

Tags: mybb

What is the suggested way to have two (or more) myBB forums on one Ubuntu server? 
Should I have /var/www/forum1, /var/www/forum2 ... and each of them with their own database in mySQL?

Comment: yes that is one possibility, but then your URL would look like: `www.example.com/forum1` and `www.example.com/forum2`

Comment: you would also need to change the .htaccess for each of these forums..